# Advanced orderby with multiple meta_query

Tags: meta-query, sort

I am on latest version of WordPress.  I have scoured the codex concerning wp_query and meta_query.  I also read through these:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/

Here are my $args for the query:

```
$args = array (
        'post_type'              => array( 'member' ),
        'tax_query'              => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'   => 'group',
                    'field'      => 'slug',
                    'terms'      => array('town-board'),
                    )
                ),
        'meta_query'             => array(
            'relation'           => 'OR',
            'chairman' =>   array(
                    'key'        => '_town-board_position',
                    'value'      => 'Town Chairman',
                    ),
            'supervisor' =>   array(
                    'key'        => '_town-board_position',
                    'value'      => 'Supervisor',
                    'compare'    => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
        'orderby'                => array(
            'supervisor'         => 'ASC',
            'chairman'           => 'DESC',
            ),
    );
```

I have tinkered with different orderby configurations, but it doesn't seem to produce the results I would like.

With the $args above I get the chairman listed first but the Supervisors are listed backwards.  So, it goes Chairman, Supervisor 3, Supervisor 2, Supervisor 1.

I want to sort this so that chairman is first and then Supervisor 1, Supervisor 2 and so on are listed in order below the chairman.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around this...

Any input would be appreciated.  If more details are needed please let me know.

Comment: with the current orderby it actually gives Supervisor 1, Supervisor 2, Supervisor 3, Chairman.  My mistake.

Comment: This is a little hard to say about in theory (without seeing data and queries). As a guess have you tried changing order withing `orderby` array, putting `chairman` directive first?

Comment: Yeah, I tried swapping them.  I tried again just now because I couldn't remember what happened.  Yeah, it doesn't matter which directive is first.  whether it is the supervisor or chairman being declared first.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: IMHO I would sort this with PHP. Such complex SQL sorting operations are quite expensive. PHP is definitely faster. Have a look at `usort()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything I could to try sorting within the WordPress functions, but was unable to get what I wanted.  I ended up following PieterGoosen's advice and do a usort().  Here is what I have now:

WP_Query $args

```
$args = array (
        'post_type'              => array( 'member' ),
        'tax_query'              => array(
            array(
                    'taxonomy'   => 'group',
                    'field'      => 'slug',
                    'terms'      => 'town-board'
                ),
        ),
    );
```

Custom sort function

```
function custom_sort($a, $b) {
        if ( get_post_meta($a->ID, '_town-board_position', true) === 'Town Chairman' ) {
            return -1;
        } else if ( strpos( get_post_meta($a->ID, '_town-board_position', true), 'Supervisor' ) !== false and strpos( get_post_meta($b->ID, '_town-board_position', true), 'Supervisor' ) !== false ) {
            return strcmp(get_post_meta($a->ID, '_town-board_position', true), get_post_meta($b->ID, '_town-board_position', true));
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Now, it sorts as I wanted Town Chairman > Supervisor 1 > 2 > 3 > 4

Thank you everyone for your suggestions.